# Gitlab upload speed 4 KiB/s

Tags: git, gitlab

Gitlab server is running in a new Docker image and the upload speed is around 4.00 KiB/s sometimes it goes up to 54.00 KiB/s but that's still slow. I have a 20Mbps connection.

Cloning is very fast though.

I'm using HTTPS to push to Git repo. Is there a workaround? I need to test SSH speed but still need https to be fixed so our clients don't have this issue.

`Upload speed:`

```
Writing objects:  17% (22/128), 24.00 KiB | 4.00 KiB/s
```

`Gitlab Server Docker image:`

```
gitlab/gitlab-ce:13.7.7-ce.0
```

`Git client version:`

```
git version 2.29.0
```

Comment: `Gitlab server is running in a new Docker image` what is the `tracepath` to that server?

Comment: Here it is.. https://pastebin.com/U7QnDWap  I modified the IP's btw